# Searching and referencing html files in js file

Tags: javascript, html

So I was doing some grasshopper HTML learning and thought that I could replicate it...

*Oh how naive, I was...*

The intention was to change text in a button when clicked

Here is the reference JS code

```js
let button1 = document.getElementById('button1');
button1.addEventListener('click', () => {
    button1.textContent = 'Clicked!';
});
```

and html reference

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <button id='button1'>Fresh Button1</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately, however much I tried to make it work, I kept getting told off by VS Code that

> Uncaught ReferenceError ReferenceError: document is not defined

I don't know how to fix it, I've tried everything, scripting it IN the HTML file, making a variable that would pull it from the html file,... (sub-question: is it possible to reference a document in JS, like the `src=""` in HTML?)

I've spent the better part of my evening grinding on this and want to throw my pc out of the window. I don't know if it's just a syntax error or if I'm using it wrong... I just don't know.

Please help, thanks

Sincerely,
Seven

Comment: How are you executing this code?

Comment: Running the html on chrome

Comment: search about script tag

Comment: I also tried running the js file alone, but just for testing and debugging, since my target was a working html file

Comment: the script tag didn't help (or i was just doing it wrong)

Comment: If you are executing the JavaScript file in a browser environment `document` should be defined.  `document` is part of the DOM API, not a part of the JavaScript language itself, so if you are trying to execute this in a non-browser context you might run into problems.  I am guessing you just need to somehow make VS Code aware of the fact that this is a file that will be running in a browser and will have access to all the expected globals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've spent the better part of my evening grinding on this and want to throw my pc out of the window. I don't know if it's just a syntax error or if I'm using it wrong... I just don't know.

Don't throw your pc out the window. There's no syntax error. You've done everything right.

> I don't know how to fix it

Trust me, there's nothing to fix.

Here is your code below.

It works:

```js
let button1 = document.getElementById('button1');

button1.addEventListener('click', () => {
    
    button1.textContent = 'Clicked!';
});
```

```html
<button type="button" id="button1">Fresh Button1</button>
```

Comment: Thanks A LOT, after you confirmed that it was right, I compared the two codes and found out that I was calling it in the wrong order. But one thing is still on my mind, VScode is still saying that 'document is not defined', so how can i make it understand that it doesn't need to be defined, because it will be running on a browser?

Comment: @7addva sounds like VsCode is using a NodeJS environment